How to decompose irregularly spaced count data?
My advisor would like to do a time series analysis on our data, but I'm not sure if it qualifies as a true "time series" dataset. The data collected are fish counts and during collection we follow the rising tide to maximize the number sites we can visit in a day (no. of sites per day range anywhere from 6 - 14). There are 47 sites and sampling can be completed in 5-6 days, 2x per year, once per season (dry/wet).
I'm aware of the function stats::decompose(), but as I understand it my data's frequency of collection doesn't match the available options (It's not quite annual, quarterly or monthly). Is the data too irregularly spaced for a time series analysis? Are there alternative functions that might work? How might I explain to my advisor the issues with trying to decompose this data (seasonality can't be captured with only 1/2 months per year? The frequency is too short?).

Note, Dry 2021 is missing b/c of COVID restrictions.
# Sites sampled per month:

>table(data_mini$Month, data_mini$CYR)

     2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023
  2     0    0    0    0    0   20    0    0    0    9    0
  3    47   39   30   24   43   27   47   47    0   38   47
  4     0    8   17   23    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  8     0   30    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  9    47   17   47   47    0   47   47   47   47   47    0
  10    0    0    0    0   47    0    0    0    0    0    0

Data:
# "CYR_Keyfield" = Calendar year, Month, Day, Site of collection

test <- subset(data_mini, select = c(CYR_Keyfield, num))
test <- arrange(test)

dput(test)

structure(list(CYR_Keyfield = c("C-2013-3-10-37", "C-2013-3-10-38", 
"C-2013-3-10-39", "C-2013-3-10-40", "C-2013-3-10-41", "C-2013-3-10-42", 
"C-2013-3-10-43", "C-2013-3-10-44", "C-2013-3-10-45", "C-2013-3-10-46", 
"C-2013-3-10-47", "C-2013-3-11-26", "C-2013-3-11-27", "C-2013-3-11-28", 
"C-2013-3-11-29", "C-2013-3-11-30", "C-2013-3-11-31", "C-2013-3-11-32", 
"C-2013-3-11-33", "C-2013-3-11-34", "C-2013-3-11-35", "C-2013-3-11-36", 
"C-2013-3-12-15", "C-2013-3-12-16", "C-2013-3-12-17", "C-2013-3-12-18", 
"C-2013-3-12-19", "C-2013-3-12-20", "C-2013-3-12-21", "C-2013-3-12-22", 
"C-2013-3-12-23", "C-2013-3-12-24", "C-2013-3-12-25", "C-2013-3-13-10", 
"C-2013-3-13-11", "C-2013-3-13-12", "C-2013-3-13-13", "C-2013-3-13-14", 
"C-2013-3-13-7", "C-2013-3-13-8", "C-2013-3-13-9", "C-2013-3-14-1", 
"C-2013-3-14-2", "C-2013-3-14-3", "C-2013-3-14-4", "C-2013-3-14-5", 
"C-2013-3-14-6", "C-2013-9-3-39", "C-2013-9-3-40", "C-2013-9-3-41", 
"C-2013-9-3-42", "C-2013-9-3-43", "C-2013-9-3-44", "C-2013-9-3-45", 
"C-2013-9-3-46", "C-2013-9-3-47", "C-2013-9-4-27", "C-2013-9-4-30", 
"C-2013-9-4-31", "C-2013-9-4-32", "C-2013-9-4-33", "C-2013-9-4-34", 
"C-2013-9-4-35", "C-2013-9-4-36", "C-2013-9-4-37", "C-2013-9-4-38", 
"C-2013-9-5-15", "C-2013-9-5-16", "C-2013-9-5-17", "C-2013-9-5-18", 
"C-2013-9-5-19", "C-2013-9-5-20", "C-2013-9-5-21", "C-2013-9-5-22", 
"C-2013-9-5-23", "C-2013-9-5-24", "C-2013-9-5-25", "C-2013-9-5-26", 
"C-2013-9-5-28", "C-2013-9-5-29", "C-2013-9-6-10", "C-2013-9-6-11", 
"C-2013-9-6-12", "C-2013-9-6-13", "C-2013-9-6-14", "C-2013-9-6-7", 
"C-2013-9-6-8", "C-2013-9-6-9", "C-2013-9-8-1", "C-2013-9-8-2", 
"C-2013-9-8-3", "C-2013-9-8-4", "C-2013-9-8-5", "C-2013-9-8-6", 
"C-2014-3-14-40", "C-2014-3-14-41", "C-2014-3-14-42", "C-2014-3-14-43", 
"C-2014-3-14-44", "C-2014-3-14-45", "C-2014-3-14-46", "C-2014-3-14-47", 
"C-2014-3-15-27", "C-2014-3-15-28", "C-2014-3-15-29", "C-2014-3-15-30", 
"C-2014-3-15-31", "C-2014-3-15-32", "C-2014-3-15-33", "C-2014-3-15-34", 
"C-2014-3-15-35", "C-2014-3-15-36", "C-2014-3-15-37", "C-2014-3-15-38", 
"C-2014-3-15-39", "C-2014-3-16-17", "C-2014-3-16-18", "C-2014-3-16-19", 
"C-2014-3-16-20", "C-2014-3-16-21", "C-2014-3-16-22", "C-2014-3-16-23", 
"C-2014-3-16-24", "C-2014-3-16-25", "C-2014-3-16-26", "C-2014-3-31-10", 
"C-2014-3-31-11", "C-2014-3-31-12", "C-2014-3-31-13", "C-2014-3-31-14", 
"C-2014-3-31-15", "C-2014-3-31-16", "C-2014-3-31-9", "C-2014-4-1-1", 
"C-2014-4-1-2", "C-2014-4-1-3", "C-2014-4-1-4", "C-2014-4-1-5", 
"C-2014-4-1-6", "C-2014-4-1-7", "C-2014-4-1-8", "C-2014-8-25-39", 
"C-2014-8-25-40", "C-2014-8-25-41", "C-2014-8-25-42", "C-2014-8-25-43", 
"C-2014-8-25-44", "C-2014-8-25-45", "C-2014-8-25-46", "C-2014-8-25-47", 
"C-2014-8-26-27", "C-2014-8-26-28", "C-2014-8-26-29", "C-2014-8-26-30", 
"C-2014-8-26-31", "C-2014-8-26-32", "C-2014-8-26-33", "C-2014-8-26-34", 
"C-2014-8-26-35", "C-2014-8-26-36", "C-2014-8-26-37", "C-2014-8-26-38", 
"C-2014-8-27-18", "C-2014-8-27-19", "C-2014-8-27-20", "C-2014-8-27-21", 
"C-2014-8-27-22", "C-2014-8-27-23", "C-2014-8-27-24", "C-2014-8-27-25", 
"C-2014-8-27-26", "C-2014-9-8-1", "C-2014-9-8-2", "C-2014-9-8-3", 
"C-2014-9-8-4", "C-2014-9-8-5", "C-2014-9-8-6", "C-2014-9-9-10", 
"C-2014-9-9-11", "C-2014-9-9-12", "C-2014-9-9-13", "C-2014-9-9-14", 
"C-2014-9-9-15", "C-2014-9-9-16", "C-2014-9-9-17", "C-2014-9-9-7", 
"C-2014-9-9-8", "C-2014-9-9-9", "C-2015-3-17-42", "C-2015-3-17-43", 
"C-2015-3-17-44", "C-2015-3-17-45", "C-2015-3-17-46", "C-2015-3-17-47", 
"C-2015-3-18-32", "C-2015-3-18-33", "C-2015-3-18-34", "C-2015-3-18-35", 
"C-2015-3-18-36", "C-2015-3-18-37", "C-2015-3-18-38", "C-2015-3-18-39", 
"C-2015-3-18-40", "C-2015-3-18-41", "C-2015-3-19-22", "C-2015-3-19-23", 
"C-2015-3-19-24", "C-2015-3-19-25", "C-2015-3-19-26", "C-2015-3-19-27", 
"C-2015-3-19-28", "C-2015-3-19-29", "C-2015-3-19-30", "C-2015-3-19-31", 
"C-2015-3-20-18", "C-2015-3-20-19", "C-2015-3-20-20", "C-2015-3-20-21", 
"C-2015-4-1-10", "C-2015-4-1-11", "C-2015-4-1-12", "C-2015-4-1-13", 
"C-2015-4-1-14", "C-2015-4-1-15", "C-2015-4-1-16", "C-2015-4-1-17", 
"C-2015-4-2-1", "C-2015-4-2-2", "C-2015-4-2-3", "C-2015-4-2-4", 
"C-2015-4-2-5", "C-2015-4-2-6", "C-2015-4-2-7", "C-2015-4-2-8", 
"C-2015-4-2-9", "C-2015-9-10-38", "C-2015-9-10-39", "C-2015-9-10-40", 
"C-2015-9-10-41", "C-2015-9-10-42", "C-2015-9-10-43", "C-2015-9-10-44", 
"C-2015-9-10-45", "C-2015-9-10-46", "C-2015-9-10-47", "C-2015-9-11-31", 
"C-2015-9-11-32", "C-2015-9-11-33", "C-2015-9-11-34", "C-2015-9-11-35", 
"C-2015-9-11-36", "C-2015-9-11-37", "C-2015-9-12-18", "C-2015-9-12-19", 
"C-2015-9-12-20", "C-2015-9-12-21", "C-2015-9-12-22", "C-2015-9-12-23", 
"C-2015-9-12-24", "C-2015-9-12-25", "C-2015-9-12-26", "C-2015-9-12-27", 
"C-2015-9-12-28", "C-2015-9-12-29", "C-2015-9-12-30", "C-2015-9-14-10", 
"C-2015-9-14-11", "C-2015-9-14-12", "C-2015-9-14-13", "C-2015-9-14-14", 
"C-2015-9-14-15", "C-2015-9-14-16", "C-2015-9-14-17", "C-2015-9-14-8", 
"C-2015-9-14-9", "C-2015-9-16-1", "C-2015-9-16-2", "C-2015-9-16-3", 
"C-2015-9-16-4", "C-2015-9-16-5", "C-2015-9-16-6", "C-2015-9-16-7", 
"C-2016-3-20-42", "C-2016-3-20-43", "C-2016-3-20-44", "C-2016-3-20-45", 
"C-2016-3-20-46", "C-2016-3-20-47", "C-2016-3-24-35", "C-2016-3-24-36", 
"C-2016-3-24-37", "C-2016-3-24-38", "C-2016-3-24-39", "C-2016-3-24-40", 
"C-2016-3-24-41", "C-2016-3-28-28", "C-2016-3-28-29", "C-2016-3-28-30", 
"C-2016-3-28-31", "C-2016-3-28-32", "C-2016-3-28-33", "C-2016-3-28-34", 
"C-2016-3-29-24", "C-2016-3-29-25", "C-2016-3-29-26", "C-2016-3-29-27", 
"C-2016-4-5-14", "C-2016-4-5-15", "C-2016-4-5-16", "C-2016-4-5-17", 
"C-2016-4-5-18", "C-2016-4-5-19", "C-2016-4-5-20", "C-2016-4-5-21", 
"C-2016-4-5-22", "C-2016-4-5-23", "C-2016-4-7-10", "C-2016-4-7-11", 
"C-2016-4-7-12", "C-2016-4-7-13", "C-2016-4-7-7", "C-2016-4-7-8", 
"C-2016-4-7-9", "C-2016-4-8-1", "C-2016-4-8-2", "C-2016-4-8-3", 
"C-2016-4-8-4", "C-2016-4-8-5", "C-2016-4-8-6", "C-2016-9-1-40", 
"C-2016-9-1-41", "C-2016-9-1-42", "C-2016-9-1-43", "C-2016-9-1-44", 
"C-2016-9-1-45", "C-2016-9-1-46", "C-2016-9-1-47", "C-2016-9-14-24", 
"C-2016-9-14-25", "C-2016-9-14-26", "C-2016-9-14-27", "C-2016-9-14-28", 
"C-2016-9-14-29", "C-2016-9-14-30", "C-2016-9-14-31", "C-2016-9-14-32", 
"C-2016-9-14-33", "C-2016-9-15-14", "C-2016-9-15-15", "C-2016-9-15-16", 
"C-2016-9-15-17", "C-2016-9-15-18", "C-2016-9-15-19", "C-2016-9-15-20", 
"C-2016-9-15-21", "C-2016-9-15-22", "C-2016-9-15-23", "C-2016-9-16-10", 
"C-2016-9-16-11", "C-2016-9-16-12", "C-2016-9-16-13", "C-2016-9-16-7", 
"C-2016-9-16-8", "C-2016-9-16-9", "C-2016-9-17-1", "C-2016-9-17-2", 
"C-2016-9-17-3", "C-2016-9-17-4", "C-2016-9-17-5", "C-2016-9-17-6", 
"C-2016-9-2-34", "C-2016-9-2-35", "C-2016-9-2-36", "C-2016-9-2-37", 
"C-2016-9-2-38", "C-2016-9-2-39", "C-2017-10-10-12", "C-2017-10-10-13", 
"C-2017-10-10-14", "C-2017-10-10-15", "C-2017-10-10-16", "C-2017-10-10-17", 
"C-2017-10-11-1", "C-2017-10-11-10", "C-2017-10-11-11", "C-2017-10-11-2", 
"C-2017-10-11-3", "C-2017-10-11-7", "C-2017-10-11-8", "C-2017-10-11-9", 
"C-2017-10-13-4", "C-2017-10-13-5", "C-2017-10-13-6", "C-2017-10-2-43", 
"C-2017-10-2-44", "C-2017-10-2-45", "C-2017-10-2-46", "C-2017-10-2-47", 
"C-2017-10-6-38", "C-2017-10-6-39", "C-2017-10-6-40", "C-2017-10-6-41", 
"C-2017-10-6-42", "C-2017-10-7-30", "C-2017-10-7-31", "C-2017-10-7-32", 
"C-2017-10-7-33", "C-2017-10-7-34", "C-2017-10-7-35", "C-2017-10-7-36", 
"C-2017-10-7-37", "C-2017-10-8-18", "C-2017-10-8-19", "C-2017-10-8-20", 
"C-2017-10-8-21", "C-2017-10-8-22", "C-2017-10-8-23", "C-2017-10-8-24", 
"C-2017-10-8-25", "C-2017-10-8-26", "C-2017-10-8-27", "C-2017-10-8-28", 
"C-2017-10-8-29", "C-2017-3-10-41", "C-2017-3-10-42", "C-2017-3-10-43", 
"C-2017-3-10-44", "C-2017-3-10-45", "C-2017-3-10-46", "C-2017-3-10-47", 
"C-2017-3-11-31", "C-2017-3-11-32", "C-2017-3-11-33", "C-2017-3-11-34", 
"C-2017-3-11-35", "C-2017-3-11-36", "C-2017-3-11-37", "C-2017-3-11-38", 
"C-2017-3-11-39", "C-2017-3-11-40", "C-2017-3-12-19", "C-2017-3-12-20", 
"C-2017-3-12-22", "C-2017-3-12-23", "C-2017-3-12-24", "C-2017-3-12-25", 
"C-2017-3-12-26", "C-2017-3-12-27", "C-2017-3-12-29", "C-2017-3-13-10", 
"C-2017-3-13-11", "C-2017-3-13-12", "C-2017-3-13-13", "C-2017-3-13-14", 
"C-2017-3-13-15", "C-2017-3-13-16", "C-2017-3-13-17", "C-2017-3-13-9", 
"C-2017-3-14-1", "C-2017-3-14-2", "C-2017-3-14-3", "C-2017-3-14-4", 
"C-2017-3-14-5", "C-2017-3-14-6", "C-2017-3-14-7", "C-2017-3-14-8", 
"C-2018-2-26-41", "C-2018-2-26-42", "C-2018-2-26-47", "C-2018-2-27-38", 
"C-2018-2-27-39", "C-2018-2-27-40", "C-2018-2-27-43", "C-2018-2-27-44", 
"C-2018-2-27-45", "C-2018-2-27-46", "C-2018-2-28-28", "C-2018-2-28-29", 
"C-2018-2-28-30", "C-2018-2-28-31", "C-2018-2-28-32", "C-2018-2-28-33", 
"C-2018-2-28-34", "C-2018-2-28-35", "C-2018-2-28-36", "C-2018-2-28-37", 
"C-2018-3-1-18", "C-2018-3-1-19", "C-2018-3-1-20", "C-2018-3-1-21", 
"C-2018-3-1-22", "C-2018-3-1-23", "C-2018-3-1-24", "C-2018-3-1-25", 
"C-2018-3-1-26", "C-2018-3-1-27", "C-2018-3-2-10", "C-2018-3-2-11", 
"C-2018-3-2-12", "C-2018-3-2-13", "C-2018-3-2-14", "C-2018-3-2-15", 
"C-2018-3-2-16", "C-2018-3-2-17", "C-2018-3-2-9", "C-2018-3-3-1", 
"C-2018-3-3-2", "C-2018-3-3-3", "C-2018-3-3-4", "C-2018-3-3-5", 
"C-2018-3-3-6", "C-2018-3-3-7", "C-2018-3-3-8", "C-2018-9-10-10", 
"C-2018-9-10-11", "C-2018-9-10-12", "C-2018-9-10-13", "C-2018-9-10-14", 
"C-2018-9-10-15", "C-2018-9-10-16", "C-2018-9-10-17", "C-2018-9-10-9", 
"C-2018-9-11-1", "C-2018-9-11-2", "C-2018-9-11-3", "C-2018-9-11-4", 
"C-2018-9-11-5", "C-2018-9-11-6", "C-2018-9-11-7", "C-2018-9-11-8", 
"C-2018-9-6-36", "C-2018-9-6-38", "C-2018-9-6-39", "C-2018-9-6-40", 
"C-2018-9-6-41", "C-2018-9-6-42", "C-2018-9-6-43", "C-2018-9-6-44", 
"C-2018-9-6-45", "C-2018-9-6-46", "C-2018-9-6-47", "C-2018-9-7-26", 
"C-2018-9-7-27", "C-2018-9-7-28", "C-2018-9-7-29", "C-2018-9-7-30", 
"C-2018-9-7-31", "C-2018-9-7-32", "C-2018-9-7-33", "C-2018-9-7-34", 
"C-2018-9-7-35", "C-2018-9-7-37", "C-2018-9-8-18", "C-2018-9-8-19", 
"C-2018-9-8-20", "C-2018-9-8-21", "C-2018-9-8-22", "C-2018-9-8-23", 
"C-2018-9-8-24", "C-2018-9-8-25", "C-2019-3-11-10", "C-2019-3-11-11", 
"C-2019-3-11-6", "C-2019-3-11-7", "C-2019-3-11-8", "C-2019-3-11-9", 
"C-2019-3-12-1", "C-2019-3-12-2", "C-2019-3-12-3", "C-2019-3-12-4", 
"C-2019-3-12-5", "C-2019-3-3-38", "C-2019-3-3-39", "C-2019-3-3-40", 
"C-2019-3-3-41", "C-2019-3-3-42", "C-2019-3-3-43", "C-2019-3-3-44", 
"C-2019-3-3-45", "C-2019-3-3-46", "C-2019-3-3-47", "C-2019-3-4-28", 
"C-2019-3-4-29", "C-2019-3-4-30", "C-2019-3-4-31", "C-2019-3-4-32", 
"C-2019-3-4-33", "C-2019-3-4-34", "C-2019-3-4-35", "C-2019-3-4-36", 
"C-2019-3-4-37", "C-2019-3-5-16", "C-2019-3-5-17", "C-2019-3-5-18", 
"C-2019-3-5-19", "C-2019-3-5-20", "C-2019-3-5-21", "C-2019-3-5-22", 
"C-2019-3-5-23", "C-2019-3-5-24", "C-2019-3-5-25", "C-2019-3-5-26", 
"C-2019-3-5-27", "C-2019-3-8-12", "C-2019-3-8-13", "C-2019-3-8-14", 
"C-2019-3-8-15", "C-2019-9-11-39", "C-2019-9-11-40", "C-2019-9-11-41", 
"C-2019-9-11-43", "C-2019-9-11-44", "C-2019-9-11-45", "C-2019-9-11-46", 
"C-2019-9-11-47", "C-2019-9-12-31", "C-2019-9-12-32", "C-2019-9-12-33", 
"C-2019-9-12-34", "C-2019-9-12-35", "C-2019-9-12-36", "C-2019-9-12-37", 
"C-2019-9-12-38", "C-2019-9-12-42", "C-2019-9-13-24", "C-2019-9-13-25", 
"C-2019-9-13-26", "C-2019-9-13-27", "C-2019-9-13-28", "C-2019-9-13-29", 
"C-2019-9-13-30", "C-2019-9-16-1", "C-2019-9-16-2", "C-2019-9-16-3", 
"C-2019-9-16-4", "C-2019-9-16-5", "C-2019-9-17-15", "C-2019-9-17-16", 
"C-2019-9-17-17", "C-2019-9-17-18", "C-2019-9-17-19", "C-2019-9-17-20", 
"C-2019-9-17-21", "C-2019-9-17-22", "C-2019-9-17-23", "C-2019-9-18-10", 
"C-2019-9-18-11", "C-2019-9-18-12", "C-2019-9-18-13", "C-2019-9-18-14", 
"C-2019-9-18-6", "C-2019-9-18-7", "C-2019-9-18-8", "C-2019-9-18-9", 
"C-2020-3-10-38", "C-2020-3-10-39", "C-2020-3-10-40", "C-2020-3-10-41", 
"C-2020-3-10-42", "C-2020-3-10-43", "C-2020-3-10-44", "C-2020-3-10-45", 
"C-2020-3-10-46", "C-2020-3-10-47", "C-2020-3-11-29", "C-2020-3-11-30", 
"C-2020-3-11-31", "C-2020-3-11-32", "C-2020-3-11-33", "C-2020-3-11-34", 
"C-2020-3-11-35", "C-2020-3-11-36", "C-2020-3-11-37", "C-2020-3-12-19", 
"C-2020-3-12-20", "C-2020-3-12-21", "C-2020-3-12-22", "C-2020-3-12-23", 
"C-2020-3-12-24", "C-2020-3-12-25", "C-2020-3-12-26", "C-2020-3-12-27", 
"C-2020-3-12-28", "C-2020-3-13-10", "C-2020-3-13-11", "C-2020-3-13-12", 
"C-2020-3-13-13", "C-2020-3-13-14", "C-2020-3-13-15", "C-2020-3-13-16", 
"C-2020-3-13-17", "C-2020-3-13-18", "C-2020-3-13-9", "C-2020-3-19-1", 
"C-2020-3-19-2", "C-2020-3-19-3", "C-2020-3-19-4", "C-2020-3-19-5", 
"C-2020-3-20-6", "C-2020-3-20-7", "C-2020-3-20-8", "C-2020-9-15-12", 
"C-2020-9-15-13", "C-2020-9-15-14", "C-2020-9-15-15", "C-2020-9-15-16", 
"C-2020-9-15-17", "C-2020-9-15-18", "C-2020-9-15-19", "C-2020-9-15-20", 
"C-2020-9-15-21", "C-2020-9-15-22", "C-2020-9-16-1", "C-2020-9-16-2", 
"C-2020-9-16-3", "C-2020-9-16-4", "C-2020-9-16-5", "C-2020-9-16-6", 
"C-2020-9-16-7", "C-2020-9-16-8", "C-2020-9-17-10", "C-2020-9-17-11", 
"C-2020-9-17-9", "C-2020-9-2-40", "C-2020-9-2-41", "C-2020-9-2-42", 
"C-2020-9-2-43", "C-2020-9-2-44", "C-2020-9-2-45", "C-2020-9-2-46", 
"C-2020-9-2-47", "C-2020-9-3-34", "C-2020-9-3-35", "C-2020-9-3-36", 
"C-2020-9-3-37", "C-2020-9-3-38", "C-2020-9-3-39", "C-2020-9-4-23", 
"C-2020-9-4-24", "C-2020-9-4-25", "C-2020-9-4-26", "C-2020-9-4-27", 
"C-2020-9-4-28", "C-2020-9-4-29", "C-2020-9-4-30", "C-2020-9-4-31", 
"C-2020-9-4-32", "C-2020-9-4-33", "C-2021-9-18-18", "C-2021-9-18-19", 
"C-2021-9-18-20", "C-2021-9-18-21", "C-2021-9-18-22", "C-2021-9-18-23", 
"C-2021-9-18-24", "C-2021-9-18-25", "C-2021-9-18-26", "C-2021-9-19-27", 
"C-2021-9-19-28", "C-2021-9-19-29", "C-2021-9-19-30", "C-2021-9-19-31", 
"C-2021-9-19-32", "C-2021-9-19-33", "C-2021-9-19-34", "C-2021-9-19-35", 
"C-2021-9-19-36", "C-2021-9-19-37", "C-2021-9-20-38", "C-2021-9-20-39", 
"C-2021-9-20-40", "C-2021-9-20-41", "C-2021-9-20-42", "C-2021-9-20-43", 
"C-2021-9-20-44", "C-2021-9-20-45", "C-2021-9-20-46", "C-2021-9-20-47", 
"C-2021-9-22-10", "C-2021-9-22-11", "C-2021-9-22-12", "C-2021-9-22-13", 
"C-2021-9-22-14", "C-2021-9-22-15", "C-2021-9-22-16", "C-2021-9-22-17", 
"C-2021-9-22-8", "C-2021-9-22-9", "C-2021-9-23-1", "C-2021-9-23-2", 
"C-2021-9-23-3", "C-2021-9-23-4", "C-2021-9-23-5", "C-2021-9-23-6", 
"C-2021-9-23-7", "C-2022-2-28-39", "C-2022-2-28-40", "C-2022-2-28-41", 
"C-2022-2-28-42", "C-2022-2-28-43", "C-2022-2-28-44", "C-2022-2-28-45", 
"C-2022-2-28-46", "C-2022-2-28-47", "C-2022-3-17-1", "C-2022-3-17-2", 
"C-2022-3-17-3", "C-2022-3-17-4", "C-2022-3-17-5", "C-2022-3-17-6", 
"C-2022-3-17-7", "C-2022-3-18-10", "C-2022-3-18-11", "C-2022-3-18-12", 
"C-2022-3-18-13", "C-2022-3-18-14", "C-2022-3-18-15", "C-2022-3-18-16", 
"C-2022-3-18-17", "C-2022-3-18-8", "C-2022-3-18-9", "C-2022-3-2-18", 
"C-2022-3-2-19", "C-2022-3-2-20", "C-2022-3-2-21", "C-2022-3-2-22", 
"C-2022-3-2-23", "C-2022-3-2-24", "C-2022-3-2-25", "C-2022-3-2-26", 
"C-2022-3-2-27", "C-2022-3-2-28", "C-2022-3-3-29", "C-2022-3-3-30", 
"C-2022-3-3-31", "C-2022-3-3-32", "C-2022-3-3-33", "C-2022-3-3-34", 
"C-2022-3-3-35", "C-2022-3-3-36", "C-2022-3-3-37", "C-2022-3-3-38", 
"C-2022-9-12-1", "C-2022-9-12-10", "C-2022-9-12-11", "C-2022-9-12-2", 
"C-2022-9-12-3", "C-2022-9-12-4", "C-2022-9-12-5", "C-2022-9-12-6", 
"C-2022-9-12-7", "C-2022-9-12-8", "C-2022-9-12-9", "C-2022-9-13-12", 
"C-2022-9-13-13", "C-2022-9-13-14", "C-2022-9-13-15", "C-2022-9-13-16", 
"C-2022-9-13-17", "C-2022-9-13-18", "C-2022-9-13-19", "C-2022-9-13-20", 
"C-2022-9-7-40", "C-2022-9-7-41", "C-2022-9-7-42", "C-2022-9-7-43", 
"C-2022-9-7-44", "C-2022-9-7-45", "C-2022-9-7-46", "C-2022-9-7-47", 
"C-2022-9-8-29", "C-2022-9-8-30", "C-2022-9-8-31", "C-2022-9-8-32", 
"C-2022-9-8-33", "C-2022-9-8-34", "C-2022-9-8-35", "C-2022-9-8-36", 
"C-2022-9-8-37", "C-2022-9-9-21", "C-2022-9-9-22", "C-2022-9-9-23", 
"C-2022-9-9-24", "C-2022-9-9-25", "C-2022-9-9-26", "C-2022-9-9-27", 
"C-2022-9-9-28", "C-2022-9-9-38", "C-2022-9-9-39", "C-2023-3-10-10", 
"C-2023-3-10-11", "C-2023-3-10-12", "C-2023-3-10-13", "C-2023-3-10-9", 
"C-2023-3-6-38", "C-2023-3-6-39", "C-2023-3-6-40", "C-2023-3-6-41", 
"C-2023-3-6-42", "C-2023-3-6-43", "C-2023-3-6-44", "C-2023-3-6-45", 
"C-2023-3-6-46", "C-2023-3-6-47", "C-2023-3-7-18", "C-2023-3-7-19", 
"C-2023-3-7-20", "C-2023-3-7-21", "C-2023-3-7-22", "C-2023-3-7-23", 
"C-2023-3-7-24", "C-2023-3-7-25", "C-2023-3-7-26", "C-2023-3-7-27", 
"C-2023-3-7-28", "C-2023-3-7-29", "C-2023-3-7-30", "C-2023-3-8-14", 
"C-2023-3-8-15", "C-2023-3-8-16", "C-2023-3-8-17", "C-2023-3-8-31", 
"C-2023-3-8-32", "C-2023-3-8-33", "C-2023-3-8-34", "C-2023-3-8-35", 
"C-2023-3-8-36", "C-2023-3-8-37", "C-2023-3-9-1", "C-2023-3-9-2", 
"C-2023-3-9-3", "C-2023-3-9-4", "C-2023-3-9-5", "C-2023-3-9-6", 
"C-2023-3-9-7", "C-2023-3-9-8"), num = c(2L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 50L, 
12L, 64L, 31L, 20L, 0L, 5L, 50L, 11L, 11L, 35L, 11L, 14L, 8L, 
1L, 6L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 68L, 1L, 17L, 25L, 5L, 90L, 
97L, 67L, 62L, 10L, 13L, 1L, 41L, 50L, 65L, 26L, 0L, 18L, 4L, 
0L, 35L, 0L, 23L, 3L, 0L, 7L, 4L, 34L, 10L, 2L, 16L, 19L, 66L, 
122L, 61L, 96L, 11L, 69L, 2L, 91L, 1L, 13L, 5L, 186L, 29L, 37L, 
63L, 69L, 44L, 20L, 25L, 30L, 22L, 46L, 25L, 16L, 50L, 55L, 39L, 
24L, 15L, 51L, 116L, 20L, 59L, 6L, 5L, 10L, 46L, 62L, 0L, 21L, 
5L, 32L, 1L, 13L, 137L, 78L, 76L, 20L, 140L, 65L, 23L, 24L, 7L, 
3L, 15L, 4L, 0L, 16L, 61L, 63L, 4L, 22L, 25L, 67L, 12L, 12L, 
22L, 52L, 51L, 144L, 108L, 40L, 52L, 0L, 28L, 58L, 63L, 168L, 
27L, 9L, 34L, 56L, 18L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 20L, 
7L, 1L, 12L, 18L, 3L, 7L, 22L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 11L, 31L, 0L, 
6L, 18L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 11L, 12L, 0L, 21L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 10L, 
24L, 0L, 21L, 2L, 2L, 17L, 13L, 4L, 38L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 16L, 24L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 12L, 1L, 14L, 7L, 6L, 14L, 
11L, 18L, 3L, 22L, 0L, 76L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 0L, 20L, 11L, 0L, 11L, 
9L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 56L, 53L, 40L, 14L, 0L, 52L, 29L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 
17L, 2L, 7L, 0L, 8L, 48L, 12L, 8L, 3L, 10L, 51L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 20L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 13L, 4L, 7L, 19L, 
21L, 14L, 33L, 41L, 18L, 8L, 27L, 33L, 7L, 25L, 5L, 1L, 14L, 
22L, 1L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 35L, 6L, 72L, 20L, 16L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 65L, 
2L, 64L, 62L, 2L, 9L, 21L, 4L, 26L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 20L, 
46L, 27L, 8L, 3L, 63L, 13L, 134L, 2L, 12L, 37L, 104L, 90L, 2L, 
52L, 23L, 9L, 3L, 16L, 0L, 75L, 13L, 45L, 67L, 7L, 3L, 0L, 8L, 
10L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 20L, 1L, 21L, 15L, 10L, 44L, 10L, 58L, 35L, 
13L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 64L, 38L, 5L, 29L, 4L, 13L, 37L, 5L, 0L, 121L, 
109L, 6L, 16L, 0L, 2L, 28L, 0L, 4L, 21L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 
0L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 11L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 11L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 8L, 0L, 32L, 1L, 
5L, 11L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 16L, 23L, 12L, 14L, 5L, 0L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 18L, 16L, 1L, 6L, 17L, 20L, 0L, 8L, 51L, 8L, 4L, 
7L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 65L, 19L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 0L, 58L, 0L, 15L, 
5L, 29L, 26L, 4L, 74L, 42L, 35L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 28L, 11L, 39L, 10L, 
18L, 21L, 30L, 18L, 22L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 46L, 74L, 93L, 8L, 2L, 
31L, 36L, 26L, 0L, 2L, 41L, 13L, 11L, 1L, 6L, 48L, 34L, 0L, 23L, 
25L, 46L, 33L, 8L, 3L, 146L, 10L, 18L, 7L, 36L, 54L, 35L, 19L, 
2L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 24L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 67L, 25L, 30L, 13L, 39L, 
49L, 15L, 44L, 55L, 20L, 5L, 3L, 38L, 14L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 15L, 11L, 
3L, 0L, 33L, 20L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 21L, 100L, 26L, 5L, 
36L, 106L, 0L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 16L, 55L, 27L, 33L, 24L, 18L, 27L, 
19L, 47L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 9L, 29L, 5L, 0L, 9L, 20L, 17L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 13L, 21L, 10L, 18L, 7L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 29L, 23L, 11L, 26L, 
0L, 14L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 22L, 8L, 20L, 182L, 22L, 0L, 35L, 6L, 13L, 
8L, 33L, 34L, 69L, 2L, 6L, 21L, 27L, 0L, 49L, 16L, 9L, 35L, 13L, 
9L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 9L, 57L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 3L, 13L, 36L, 
3L, 12L, 7L, 64L, 4L, 49L, 2L, 0L, 106L, 4L, 35L, 30L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 17L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 0L, 2L, 25L, 
10L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 37L, 17L, 0L, 18L, 29L, 33L, 10L, 
5L, 8L, 15L, 0L, 22L, 16L, 3L, 9L, 36L, 2L, 14L, 6L, 15L, 10L, 
7L, 0L, 1L, 21L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
7L, 2L, 18L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 126L, 0L, 11L, 126L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 
12L, 26L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 3L, 61L, 14L, 25L, 14L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 
12L, 2L, 1L, 18L, 0L, 2L, 25L, 1L, 0L, 9L, 64L, 1L, 6L, 97L, 
7L, 5L, 21L, 3L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 3L, 0L, 68L, 66L, 41L, 45L, 45L, 
97L, 47L, 19L, 37L, 86L, 81L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 4L, 
10L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 28L, 16L, 0L, 116L, 77L, 140L, 
38L, 56L, 22L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 32L, 1L, 0L, 66L, 6L, 70L, 22L, 
0L, 24L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 14L, 7L, 11L, 
0L, 33L, 29L, 50L, 8L, 13L, 30L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
0L, 0L, 15L, 36L, 1L, 27L, 25L, 145L, 40L, 23L, 65L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 0L, 16L, 
14L, 14L, 12L, 14L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 26L, 3L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 8L, 3L, 
0L, 4L, 55L, 51L, 32L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 16L, 
7L, 26L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 30L, 79L, 1L, 27L, 30L, 2L, 20L, 22L, 12L, 
0L, 24L, 27L, 1L, 8L, 0L, 44L, 63L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 19L, 1L, 54L, 
52L, 155L, 14L, 136L, 31L, 54L, 75L, 9L, 34L, 30L, 7L, 0L, 40L, 
27L, 31L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 30L, 124L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-936L), class = "data.frame")


There is no such thing as a “true time series data set” other than one that consists of observations collected sequentially in time. We might distinguish between lots of short series (longitudinal data) and longer sequences of data (time series) but at some point these overlap. You need to define what it is you want to ask of the data, and how you want to account for the lack of independence of the observations. A GAM is likely a good option here, as the unevenness of the sampling will complicate classical time series methods (as would the count response)

@GavinSimpson, thank you for your input! I initially gravitated towards a GA(M)M as well, but didn't have a good argument for why a classical time series analysis wouldn't work. I thought the classical time series analysis would help identify seasonal or cyclic patterns, show if the the main trend is decreasing or increasing or shows signs of a change in variance with time. I think a GAMM would definitely work, but also don't understand the main difference between the two approaches (1/2).

The main objective is to see what the global annual and seasonal trend of the data looks like, particularly between 2013-18 and 2018-23, to see if habitat restoration efforts seem to coincide with a change in abundance (2/2).
